# 400 error in Create React App / Apollo Client running locally attempting to access GraphQL API

Tags: create-react-app, react-apollo

I'm running a Create React App project locally which uses Apollo Client. I'm attempting to connect to a live GraphQL API.

When I navigate to the GraphQL API in my browser it works. I get the GraphQL playground with no errors.

When I try to use the endpoint in Apollo Client I'm getting a 400 Bad Request error.

If I run a query with the Apollo Dev Tools in Chrome it works fine.

It's been a long time since I worked on this project but it used to work fine so I'm not sure what's changed.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a malformed query.